# mysql validating data from multiple tables data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

## Edited

I realized that I did not included the brand code ID now master table holds the brand ID where only 1001 and 1002 are the ones that I care about the other brands been third party brands.

### end edited part

first thanks to all the community for the help provided in here, is been very useful all the time.
I am a completely noob at mysql, I develop java, javascript and currently php, in my current project I face an issue where I need to retrieve data from our database, considering that I cannot modify in any way none of the databases the problem is as follow:

Having a shopping site that sells different brands including two own brands for the example lets name them "puma", "nike", "ownbrand1" and "ownbrand2", the warehouse only keep stock of "ownbrand1" and "ownbrand2", if a customer buy any of the other brands the third company will send the requested product as on need basis.
The website offers the choice of filtering results in many was, one of which is by showing only items that we currently have on stock at the moment.

Say we have 3 tables, the first table, lets call it "stock" have the stock amount with internal unique code for each product (own brands only) the second "master" have the information of every single product with unique code id and general product id and the third table "photo" hold the pictures for the purpose of showing on the website holding the picture information and the general product id.

The products are identified by unique product code id different for each product that means that the same product but different size or color will have different code id, the second id general product id is different only for each product, that means that different size or color wil have the same product id and the picture information that is the picture of one of the products in general.

```
------------------------------ 
          Stock 
------------------------------ 
ID            Name         Stock 
00001     puma1             0 
00002     puma2             0 
00003     ownbrand1(s)      0 
00004     ownbrand2(l)      0 
00005     nike              0 
00006     ownbrand1(l)      1 
00007     ownbrand1(m)      3 

---------------------------------------------
        Master 
---------------------------------------------
 ID         Name         GeneralId    BrandId
00001   puma1             pum001      1030
00002   puma2             pum001      1030
00003   ownbrand1(s)      owbr001     1001
00004   ownbrand2(l)      owbr002     1002
00005   nike              nike001     1040
00006   ownbrand1(l)      owbr001     1001
00007   ownbrand1(m)      owbr001     1001

------------------------------ 
        Photo 

------------------------------ 
GeneralId    　Picture
pum001  　 　 pum001.jpg
owbr001  　  owbr001.jpg
owbr002　 　 owbr002.jpg
nike001  　  nike001.jpg
```

If the option for only stock items is clicked the page will show the items from third party and only the ones with stock gratter than 0 from ownbrand in this case will show

## Desired result

"puma" = show
 
 "nike" = show
 "ownbrand1" = show (because it have stock in some sizes)
 
 "ownbrand2" = not shown (because there is no stock)

Right now I accomplish the task doing first this query:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT stock.*, master.*  FROM stock, master WHERE master.ID = stock.ID AND stock.stock > '0'"
```

Then generate an array with the generalID code of the items on stock taking it from the master table, and then generate the follow query:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM master WHERE generalID NOT IN $previous_array"
```

and join the two arrays to generate the whole list of products brand to show doing this last query after some more filtering for categorizing:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM photo WHERE generalID IN $complete_array"
```

Now this method is giving me the result I need but as you can expect with over 2000 items and 30+ brands it does compromise the performance speed a bit, I tried doing UNION query but I really could not get my head around the idea.

If any of you sql masters could help me understand this I would be a very happy bunny.

Comment: Post desired output, based on provided sample data.

Comment: Edited post to show properly the desired result

Comment: What does `?` mean in `stock` column of `stock` table?

Comment: in this example it means that I dont know the current stock of the product as there are not my own brand, so it has to be completely irrelevant for the query, it could be 0 or 100, but I dont know that

Comment: So it is some positive value, not a question mark as a value in that column. Correct?

Comment: it will be most probably 0 not a question mark or any positive value, since we don't have way to know the real stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 (SELECT * 
 FROM stock 
   inner join master using (ID) 
   inner join photo using (generalID)
 WHERE (master.BrandId!=1001 and master.BrandId!=1002) or stock.stock>0
 ) as whatever
GROUP BY master.generalID
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, it works but on all the products, the problem I face is that I only ned to do the stock check on wonbrand1 and ownbrand2 the other brands will be shown no matter what

Comment: How are you storing whether or not the product is your own brand? Is there a boolean field somewhere, will the stock be set to NULL, will the generalID always start with 'owbr'?

Comment: by brand code, for the example is just ownbrand1 and ownbrand2 you can assume it as ownbrand1 = 1001 and ownbrand2 = 1020, stock will be set to 0 not null, there is no boolean in the tables and the general id will be given by the company making the product so it will be completely random

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not seeing a column that could be used to distinguish between own brands and third party brands. If you were add a bit column, say 'own_brand', that was set to 1 if it was your brand you could change the where to: `WHERE own_brand=0 or sum(stock.stock)>0`

Comment: please check the edit on the master table, thank you very much

Comment: So the values 1001, 1002, 1003, ... 1009 will be reserved for your own brands? This limits you to 9 'own brands', but changing the where to: `WHERE BrandId>1009 or sum(stock.stock)>0` will work if that is accurate.

Comment: Thanks Michael in reality we only have 2 own brands. in your first suggestion how will it handle the other brands where stock is 0? for example 1020 and 1030?

Comment: also is giving me this error: #1052 - Column 'BrandId' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Any brand that is neither 1001 nor 1002 will short circuit before reaching stock>0, so any brand other than 1001 and 1002 will be listed regardless of stock. To fix error #1052, add the table name as a qualifier.

Comment: Men I must sound like a total idiot, but now I get this #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: I changed it so that it no longer uses the aggregate function `SUM()` in the where clause.